# Python3 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, tkinter

The error:
Python3 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'datetime.date'

The code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from datetime import date, datetime

def get_events():
    list_events = []
    with open('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            current_event = line.split(',')
            event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
            current_event[1] = event_date
            list_events.append(current_event)
    return list_events

def days_between_dates(date1, date2):
    time_between = str(date1-date2)
    number_of_days = time_between.split(' ')
    return number_of_days[0]
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, bg='black')
c.pack()
c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='w', fill='orange', \
              font='Arial 28 bold underline', text='My Countdown Calendar')

events = get_events()
today = date.today()

for event in events:
    event_name = event[0]
    days_until = days_between_dates(events[1], today)
    display = 'It is %s days until %s' % (days_until, event_name)
    c.create_text(100, 100, anchor='w', fill='lightblue', \
                  font='Arial 28 bold', text=display)
```

the events.txt file

Anniversary,26/04/18 Birthday,14/06/18 Last day of school,04/05/18
Christmas,25/12/18

Comment: What does `events` print?

Comment: you can't subtract a function (`datetime.date`) from a widget. My guess is, `date1` and `date2` are not what you think that are in `days_between_dates`.

Comment: You have a simple typo - you are doing `events[1]` when you mean `event[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

You have a simple typo - you are doing `events[1]` when you mean `event[1]`.

Comment: I'd love to know why this is getting downvoted? I think it's the reason for the stated error...

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. I see typos like this all the time. Downvoters might be confused seeing the clear `event[0]` and not noticing incorrect `events[1]` reference on the next line